# I want to insert my photo below the name and on the right side inline with the email and number etc

Tags: latex, pdflatex, overleaf

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{palatino}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{url}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pdfgentounicode=1
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\medskip
    \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}\small 
                        \textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}
                      \end{minipage}}
                            \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{center} \fontsize{15}{15} \textbf{NAME} \end{center}
\photo{2.5cm}{photo.jpg}
Roll No.: \textbf{XXXX/XX/XX} \\
Email-id : \textbf{email@gmail.com} \\
Mobile No.: \textbf{9999999999} \\
\href{https://www.linkedin.com}{LinkedIn Profile} \\
\end{document}
```

I want to insert my photo below the name and on the right side inline with the email and number etc.
I tried this - \photo{2.5cm}{photo.jpg}.
But undefined control sequence error is occuring. I imported the graphicx module.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `minipage`s to place an image next to the other text:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
%-----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[margin=10mm]{geometry}
\raggedbottom
\usepackage{palatino}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}\selectfont
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.75}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{pbox}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{url}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\pdfgentounicode=1
%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{\medskip
    \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}\small 
                        \textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}
                      \end{minipage}}
                            \par\medskip}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{\textbf{#1}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\linespread{1.25}

\begin{center} \fontsize{15}{15} \textbf{NAME} \end{center}
%\photo{2.5cm}{photo.jpg}
\begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
Roll No.: \textbf{XXXX/XX/XX} \\
Email-id : \textbf{email@gmail.com} \\
Mobile No.: \textbf{9999999999} \\
\href{https://www.linkedin.com}{LinkedIn Profile} \\
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.55\textwidth}
\hfill\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```